# How to handle an Akka HTTP route recursively

Tags: akka, akka-http

I have a scenario where the route contains alternating segments of key/value pairs. The number of pairs is undefined, what is the effective way to collect those pairs. For example, the route may look like

```
/key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3
```

and I would like get a linkedmap with

```
(key1, value1) -> (key2, value2) -> (key3, value3)
```

I know that we can get a list of path segments and convert them as above. But what I am looking for is something that navigates the path down like

```
class EntitiesSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest with Directives {

  def lastSegment:Directive1[String] = path(Segment)
  def intermediate: Directive1[String] = <processing the intermediate>

  val navigate = (intermediate & navigate) ~ lastSegment
  val route = navigate { (param1:String) =>
    complete(param1)
  }

  "this should call the route" should {
    "invoke a route /hello" in {
      Get("/hello/world/hello1/world1/hello3/world3") ~> route ~> check {
        println(responseAs[String])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another good one would be, for example, if you have a path like

```
/12/1/5/6/8
```

How to define a directive that can add the numbers recursively? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't Use Path for Key/Value Pairs**

The methodology described in the question is an anti-pattern.  Key/value pairing can be accomplished much easier in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms).  By using the [`parameterMap`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterMap.html) Directive it becomes trivial to convert the key/value pairs into a list of `String` tuples:

```
//matches a uri of the form: /?key1=value1&key2=value2
val queryStringRoute = 
  parameterMap { params =>
    val linkedPairList : List[(String, String)] = params.toList
  }
```

**Don't Use Recursion on Directives**

A Recursive Directive is also ill-advised.  [A `Route` is declared as a simple `Function1`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/index.html#Route=akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]):

```
type Route = (RequestContext) ⇒ Future[RouteResult]
```

Because the return type is a `Future` then any recursion would have to be an operation on the original Future.  Therefore, the original calling stack cannot be ignored and the recursion will never be tail optimized.  With a long enough Path it is possible to cause a stackoverflow of the recursive function.

**If You Have to Use the Path**

When you have no other choice but to use the `Path` then you can just do some `String` parsing:

```
val pathToKeyValuePairs : Uri.Path => List[(String, String)] =
  (_ : Uri.Path)
    .toString
    .split('/')
    .grouped(2)
    .map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1))
    .toList
```

This parser can now be used inside of a `Route`:

```
val unadvisedRoute = 
  extractRequest { request =>
    val linkedPairList : List[(String, String)] = 
      pathToKeyValuePairs(request.uri.path)
  }
```